# What are the Powerbi-embedded authentication options?

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Need some help trying to figure out my authentication options for using the embedded service in an app owns data scenario.

Is the only way to authenticate and generate tokens by using your Azure AD credentials?  I have went through the examples and got everything running just fine but....

Here at the university that I work at our credentials change every quarter.  This means all 10 or so apps where I need embedded reports will have down time as I update this information every quarter.   This is going to create a lot of work.  Not only that but I really don't like the idea of the rest of the developers on the team managing the code having access to my personal AD account which is tied to lots of other personal university resources..payroll.. etc..

Am I missing something is there not another way to go about setting this up?
Is there anyway to setup a separate membership provider to authenticate against?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, just don't use your personal account for that. Use a dedicated one, with access only to what it needs.

Comment: Unfortunately being in a large university accounts are tightly regulated and I cannot get another account for these purposes.

Comment: As @AndreyNikolov mentioned you need to use a separate dedicated AAD account that is going to be the admin of Power BI. Your web app will use this credentials to authenticate against AAD. It's certainly not a good idea to use your own account or any physical's person one. What will happen if this person leaves the organization?

Comment: Thanks for responses, and I totally agree with your solution. However, as I have stated I have NO control over AAD accounts.  So unless there is a different solution my options are 1) use personal ad account. 2) use obfuscated personal ad account or 3) don't use PBI.  Options 1 and 2 are both bad options so guess I have to go with option 3.  I just wanted to confirm that I was not missing something before I abandoned PBI as a solution.

Comment: Your service accounts should not be on the same password policy as user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a service principal is a better approach for you. Instead of using a service account with a username and password you use a secure API KEY instead.

See below link, there are some limitations using a service principal as apposed to a master account:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-service-principal#service-principal-vs-master-account

But no, your not missing anything you if you want to use app owns the data model with a master account you'll have to know the username and password and ideally that should be a limited account that only has the access it needs, is not on the same password policy as normal user accounts where its password can expire etc.